# What's the output of hash index in `EXPLAIN`?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am analyzing performance of SQL queries. I am using `EXPLAIN`.

I successfully built hash index. However, the output of `EXPLAIN` still shows `Seq Scan`. Is there something wrong? What's the supposed output of hash index in `EXPLAIN`?

```
xxx=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE select xxx from xxx where sex = 'Male';

                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on xxx  (cost=0.00..3971.00 rows=113637 width=4) (actual time=0.033..74.588 rows= 113637 loops=1)
```

Comment: Postgres thinks the best execution plan is a sequential scan.  Without more information, we really cannot add more insight.

Comment: What's the query you're **EXPLAIN**ing?

Comment: Query Added. In theory, hash index would be good for equality search. Maybe the output is too large so that Postgre believes just scan the file.

Comment: In most cases hash indexes do not have any advantage over a btree index (at least in Postgres). Plus: hash indexes are not crash-safe. How many rows does the table have and how many rows are returned from that query?

Comment: What is the block size of your database? Width of the record is fairly small (4), so optimizer might think that all the records can be read from the single table block, instead of reading index and the table blocks. Also, the value you filtering against might belong to most_common_vals (which make sense for 'Male'), so again, optimizer expects to read all the data blocks anyways and doesn't bother reading the index.